# ZMQ pair (for signaling) is blocking because of bad connection

Tags: python, zeromq, blocking, pyzmq

I have two threads. One is a `Worker Thread`, the other a `Communication Thread`.

The `Worker Thread` is reading data off a serial port, doing some processing, and then enqueueing the results to be sent to a server.

The `Communication Tthread` is reading the results off the queue, and sending it. The challenge is that connectivity is wireless, and although usually present, it can be spotty (dropping in and out of range for a few minutes), and I don't want to block `Worker Thread` if I lose connectivity.

The pattern I have chosen for this, is as follows:

`Worker Thread` has an `enqueue` method which adds the message to a `Queue`, then send a signal to `inproc://signal` using a `zmq.PAIR`.

`Communication Thread` uses `zmq.DEALER` to communicate to the server (a `zmq.ROUTER`), but polls the `inproc://signal` pair in order to register whether there is a new message needing sending or not.

The following is a simplified example of the pattern:

```
import Queue
import zmq
import time
import threading
import simplejson


class ZmqPattern():
    def __init__(self):
        self.q_out = Queue.Queue()
        self.q_in = Queue.Queue()
        self.signal = None
        self.API_KEY = 'SOMETHINGCOMPLEX'
        self.zmq_comm_thr = None

    def start_zmq_signal(self):
        self.context = zmq.Context()

        # signal socket for waking the zmq thread to send messages to the relay
        self.signal = self.context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
        self.signal.bind("inproc://signal")

    def enqueue(self, msg):
        print("> pre-enqueue")
        self.q_out.put(msg)
        print("< post-enqueue")

        print(") send sig")
        self.signal.send(b"")
        print("( sig sent")

    def communication_thread(self, q_out):
        poll = zmq.Poller()

        self.endpoint_url = 'tcp://' + '127.0.0.1' + ':' + '9001'

        wake = self.context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
        wake.connect("inproc://signal")
        poll.register(wake, zmq.POLLIN)

        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
        self.socket.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, self.API_KEY)
        self.socket.connect(self.endpoint_url)
        poll.register(self.socket, zmq.POLLIN)

        while True:
            sockets = dict(poll.poll())

            if self.socket in sockets:
                message = self.socket.recv()
                message = simplejson.loads(message)

                # Incomming messages which need to be handled on the worker thread
                self.q_in.put(message)

            if wake in sockets:
                wake.recv()
                while not q_out.empty():
                    print(">> Popping off Queue")
                    message = q_out.get()
                    print(">>> Popped off Queue")
                    message = simplejson.dumps(message)
                    print("<<< About to be sent")
                    self.socket.send(message)
                    print("<< Sent")

    def start(self):
        self.start_zmq_signal()
        # ZMQ Thread
        self.zmq_comm_thr = threading.Thread(target=self.communication_thread, args=([self.q_out]))
        self.zmq_comm_thr.daemon = True
        self.zmq_comm_thr.name = "ZMQ Thread"
        self.zmq_comm_thr.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = ZmqPattern()
    test.start()

    print '###############################################'
    print '############## Starting comms #################'
    print "###############################################"

    last_debug = time.time()
    test_msg = {}
    for c in xrange(1000):
        key = 'something{}'.format(c)
        val = 'important{}'.format(c)
        test_msg[key] = val

    while True:
        test.enqueue(test_msg)
        if time.time() - last_debug > 1:
            last_debug = time.time()
            print "Still alive..."
```

If you run this, you'll see the dealer blocks as there is no router on the other end, and shortly after, the pair blocks as the `Communication Thread` isn't receiving

How should I best set up the inproc zmq to not block `Worker Thread`.

FYI, the most the entire system would need to buffer is in the order of 200k messages, and each message is around 256 bytes.

Comment: So you're using a ZMQ inproc to arbitrate access to a python `Queue`. Why not use ZMQ's queueing directly? PUSH-PULL comes to mind.

Comment: Won't that just block in the same way?

Comment: Yes it was more of a general comment. Answer below on why you're blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dealer socket has a limit on the number of messages it will store, called the high water mark. Right below your dealer socket creation, try:

```
    self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    self.socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDHWM, 200000)
```

And set that number as high as you dare; the limit is your machine's memory.

EDIT:

Some good discussion of high water marks in this question:

[Majordomo broker: handling large number of connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120776/majordomo-broker-handling-large-number-of-connections)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to field out the question before taking action as I'm never fully certain of the repercussions. If I set the HWM on the Dealer socket, it will then still receive all the inproc signals from the pair socket, and everything will continue as expected right? Do you feel the better solution is to have it buffered in the sender queue/kernel buffer rather than using a semaphore between the Worker Thread and Communication Thread - buffering the messages to the Queue, but without sending the inproc signal?

Comment: Assuming you never want to drop messages, and assuming your consumer can go away at any time, you must either 1) have an unbounded queue in which to store them or 2) pause the process that is creating them when you hit the limit of your queue. One thing that is unclear: does the worker need to work for some other reason than to produce these messages; that is, does it perform some necessary function that needs to happen regardless of whether anyone is listening?

Comment: Regarding the signal, I feel it is totally unnecessary, because if you're queueing you can always do a blocking wait on the queue itself, which will unblock as soon as new items are added to the queue.

Comment: Yeah - the worker does important functions other than sending messages, hence the separation. I see your point about the signal being unnecessary - in my actual code, there are a number of signals from a number of threads (there certainly ZMQ patterns which would work for this), I chose the signal because from what I understand polling this way was more efficient than a blocking wait on the queue (code running on embedded computer). Not sure if this is true though :)